# How to launch app from URLs in chrome that match the regex?

Tags: android, url, android-deep-link

I came across this article - https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking - and it only tells me how to open every page that matches the scheme. Let's assume I have a link https://example.com/image/img1234.html and I don't want to launch every page under https://example.com/image/ but I want to launch every page that's under /image/ and that matches regex `img\d+\.html`. I thought I could always launch every link under /image/ and then check if it matches the regex, if not, it opens the page in chrome (would it even work?), but I don't think it's an optimal solution. So how could I do this? Thank you

Comment: use firebase app indexing  click the link for more details https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/

Comment: I don't think that'd help, because the site isn't mine